# doDelete и doPut в Servlet

Tags: java, http, servlet, веб-сервер

Подскажите как сервлет определяет что пришел именно DoDelete запрос, если в форме можно указать только GET/POST методы? Напрммер если я заполнил в форме что нужно удалить и нажал на кнопку, запрос пошел на сервер и дошел до сервлета, а вот теперь как понять сервлету что именно DoDelete метод нужно вызвать а не doPost?

Comment: Никак. Если пришёл не DELETE-запрос, вызовется не doDelete.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но сервер получает Ваш HTTP-запрос и обрабатывает его (в том числе определяет что это за запрос: GET, POST, DELETE и т.д.) и вызывает соответствующий метод в сервлете.

Comment: Не нужно язвить. Пример можно? Атрибут method принимает только get или post.

Comment: А кто мешает сделать post запрос по адресу "/someurl/object/delete"?

Comment: @Ri a а смысл тогда в методе doDelete, если я могу сделать отдельно сервлет назвать его delete и там переопределить метод doPost?

Comment: Я здесь и пытаюсь понять и получить вопрос (нормальный) на 2 своих вопроса, если кто-то знает, прошу поделится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Господа, вот в чем дело, получается такая ситуация, что в html тег form отправляет только GET и POST значения, казалось бы где остальные методы HTTP протокола, так вот оказывается есть возможность отправить все остальные методы типа DELETE, PUT, HEAD, и так далее, отправляя их через javascript. Вот так. И куча информации в интернете только то и делает, что путает. Спасибу всем за обсуждение данной темы.

Comment: Вардан, можешь пожалуйста детальнее описать, как решить эту проблему, 2 дня уже с ума схожу с этим doDelete. Как с помощью js вызвать doDelete из моего сервлета?

Comment: Например используя ajax делаешь реквест 

 $.ajax({ url: `/api/photo/${$(this).attr('Id')}`, method: "DELETE" })
            .then(function (data) {
                some code...
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                some code...
            });

и в сервлете переопределаешь метод onDelete()

Answer (score 0):

Спецификация HTTP определяет структуру HTTP запросов и ответов. Согласно ней, HTTP запрос имеет следующую структуру:

1. The request line (содержит метод, URL, версию протокола);
2. The request headers;
3. An empty line (свидетельствует о том, что закончились request headers);
4. Message body (необязательно).

Пример HTTP GET запроса:

> **GET** https://www.w3.org HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: www.w3.org
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,uk;q=0.7
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181
>   Safari/537.36

В первой строке содержится название метода (GET, POST, DELETE, HEAD, PUT, ...). Вот так веб сервер (да, да, не сервлет, а веб сервер) определяет какой пришел запрос от пользователя. Далее HTTP запрос он преобразовывает в HttpServletRequest, формирует HttpServletResponse и передает в качестве параметров подходящему сервлету. А подходящий сервлет сервер находит по URL-у, который Вы определили в *servlet-mapping* -> *url-pattern* в дескрипторе развертывания *web.xml*.

В книге [Head First Servlets and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009Z45JAI) это все подробно описано.

Comment: Очень интересно, но именно метод service() определяет какой метод вызвать у сервлета, по методу в  request line. Именно так и написано в книге Head First Servlets and JSP. А что серверу определять? Какой запрос, да в request line от пользователя и так все определено какой метод, он на основании этих данных формирует два объекта и передает дальше. И это не ответ на мой вопрос. Ответ я сам написал выше.